# Resize image on Splash screen in react-native

Tags: image, react-native, resize, splash-screen, image-resizing

I'm new to react native and need help with image size on my Splash screen.
I have tried to implement all possible solutions from other similar questions but they didn't work out. Please help.

My icon (48px) is occupying the full page. What should I change?

```
var bg = require('./../../assets/bg.png')
var logo = require('./../../assets/logo_48px.png')

const {SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT} = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class Splash extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <ImageBackground source={bg} styles= {{height:'100%', width:'100%'}}>
            <View  style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

             <Image source={logo}  style={{height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.65, width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.65 }}></Image>

            </View>
     </ImageBackground>
    

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried resizeMode for image?

Comment: Yes,... I did set resizeMode:'contain' for the image as well.

Comment: You should check this link https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen